# How can I generate random numbers between 0 and a user input number?

Tags: java, prng

I'm pretty new to Java and this website, and I'm sorry if this question has already been asked  but if it isn't to hard, an answer would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Look to the right, in `Related`.

Comment: Hi.  Have you tried anything yet?  Or done any research?  Or used the search facility on this site?

Comment: I think this answer is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1377218/783510

Answer (score 0):

Psuedocode

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

...

private Random rand = new Random();
private Scanner scan = new Scanner();

...

public static int randomInt() {
    return rand.nextInt(scan.nextInt());
}
```